# Addition of defaults to components in AngularJS

Tags: angular.js, typescript, modules

I wrote a [small module in typescript](https://github.com/KevinRamharak/ng-sane-defaults/tree/fc5e7027dad4af013339f8616484686bef144993) that augments the angularjs `registerComponent` function to provide a new way of default values for the component controller.

This module was written to solve the problem of not having a nice non-biolerplatey way of providing default values for components. Another problem it attempts to solve is to prevent the default value not applying if a value was provided trough bindings but the value is undefined or null.

The module works by using a static property on the component controller called `$defaults`. Getter functions are also supported to provide dynamic defaults for each component instance.

I wrote it with dynamic getters in mind. Because it is a function you could do anything in the function body (for example call an API).

I am looking for some feedback on the code and its purpose. The source code is available.

```
(function() {
type Dict<T = any> = { [key: number]: T, [key: string]: T };

angular.module('ng-sane-defaults', []).config([
    '$compileProvider',
    function configure($compileProvider: angular.ICompileProvider) {
        // get the original `registerComponent` function
        const registerComponent = $compileProvider.component;

        // override the original function
        $compileProvider.component = component;

        /**
         * 
         * @param nameOrDict name or Dictionary of component names and their options
         * @param options options for the component if the first parameter is the name
         */
        function component(this: angular.ICompileProvider, nameOrDict: string|Dict<angular.IComponentOptions>, options?: angular.IComponentOptions) {
            // make sure the function signature is correct, if not pass it trough to the original function to handle errors
            if (typeof nameOrDict === 'string' && typeof options !== 'object')
                return registerComponent.call(this, nameOrDict, options as any);
            if (typeof nameOrDict !== 'string' && typeof nameOrDict !== 'object')
                return registerComponent.call(this, nameOrDict, options as any);

            // create the dictionary call signature as it is easier to work with
            const components: Dict<angular.IComponentOptions> = (typeof nameOrDict === 'string') ? { [nameOrDict]: options! } : nameOrDict;

            for (const key in components) {
                const options = components[key];

                // check if it has a controller function
                if (typeof options.controller !== 'function')
                    continue;

                // check if it has a `static $defaults` property, use `getOwnPropertyNames` to check for a getter function without invoking it
                if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(options.controller).indexOf('$defaults') === -1)
                    continue;

                // get the original `$onInit` function or undefined if there was none
                const onInit: Function|undefined = options.controller.prototype.$onInit;

                // patch the `$onInit` function
                options.controller.prototype.$onInit = function $onInit() {
                    const defaults = (options.controller as Dict).$defaults;

                    if (typeof defaults === 'object') {
                        for (const prop in defaults) {
                            if (this[prop] == null) {
                                this[prop] = defaults[prop];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // call the lifecycle hook if it existed
                    return (typeof onInit === 'function') ? onInit.call(this) : void 0;
                };
            }

            return registerComponent.call(this, components);
        }
    }
]);
})();
```

You can check [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/c5SW6kDUsovsczGY1rOL?p=preview) plunkr to see it in action